# Keystore android forgotten: new app and admob

Tags: android, admob, keystore

unfortenly I lost my keystore password, so I tried brute force but nothing helped to find my pw.

I created a new keystore and a new app package name.

I deleted the old app and publish the new one.

my question is about admob.

The admob banner and interstitial are the same of the first application one, and if i go to admob console, those banners are linked to the app i deleted from the play store.

I can't link another app to these banners, but the banners are the same so the views or clicks should go okay.

Does anyone know if are there any problems? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any problem.
But if it doubt, create a new app and new adUnits.